# Toolbar above keybord

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-toolbar

how I added a tool bar above the keyboard in android studio.Edit text click event show keyboard with tool bar and hide keyboard with tool bar 
here is my XML code.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">



            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tool"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/photo_gray_icon"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/photo_gray_icon"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/photo_gray_icon"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/photo_gray_icon"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please add more description.

Comment: please share more info like screenshot of what you want

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest file  add line   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  for the activity which has edit text

```
<activity
        android:name="com.ebookread.activity.MainActivity"

        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
```

Comment: can you elaborate the question?

Answer (score 0):

add this line in youe onCreate

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```